# Two If statements inside each other in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I tried to write two `If` statements inside each other in VBA, but it gives me wrong answer.  When I debug it, it shows that the program doesn't go through the `ElseIf` and keeps going with the else of the first `If`.

How can I have two `If` statements working properly inside each other?
Code:

```
If ConfigBox.Value <> ... Then

     If ListBox1.Value = ... Then

          DO  SOMETHING
    Else
          DO  SOMETHING
    End If

ElseIf ListBox1.Value = ... Or ListBox1.Value = ... Then

    DO  SOMETHING
Else

    DO  SOMETHING
End If
```

Comment: Can you explain your statements? What are they trying to do?  If/Else/End If works, why not use multiple `ElseIf`? Can you expand a little on what the statements are actually looking at?

Comment: Have you tried nesting a `Select Case` instead of another `If`? I'm guessing the elses and elseifs are messing to each other in this structure

Comment: You might want to post your code, there must be something blocking the ElseIF it is being skipped.

Comment: Code makes sense, agree with Rdster that you should post full code. Something else is interferring

Comment: Thanks everyone, the code is too large, but what i want to do is that, if the value of ConfigBox wasn't equal to the certain value it goes through the ListBox1 and check the value of that . Otherwise I want it to go through the elseif and compare the value of ListBox1 and do another operation. considering that configBox has different choices and at the first line i want to put exception for one of them. So, lines 2 through 6 should be the inner if statement in the main if statement .

Comment: `DO` is not used in VBA If Statements...

Comment: @amy - When you have a narrow problem, but a large block of code, you should write a small test program, including inputs, that exhibits the same problem. Then you generate a well formed question that someone can help you with. Often, building the small test program is enough for you to diagnose the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Your nesting is a bit off.  You would want to do something like this:

```
If ConfigBox.Value <> ... Then

    If ListBox1.Value = ... Then
          Code
    ElseIF ListBox1.Value = ... Or ListBox1.Value = ... Then
          Code
    Else
        Code 'if ListBox1.Value doesn't meet above criteria
    End If

Else
    Code 'if ConfigBox criteria is not met.  You could start another nested If for the ListBox1 here too.

End If
```

Comment: Yes that's the question but how can i write that because in this order it will go through the wrong sequences.

Comment: @Amy how so?  You will need to edit your question to explain in writing the sequence you need to check.

Answer (score 0):

try with below

```
If ((ConfigBox.Value <> "1") And (ListBox1.Value = "2")) Then
    'Do Something
ElseIf ((ConfigBox.Value <> "1") And (ListBox1.Value <> "2")) Then
    'Do Something
ElseIf ListBox1.Value = "3" Or ListBox1.Value = "4" Then
    'Do Something
Else
    'Do Something
End If
```